# Busca em query lambda com operadores lógicos

Tags: c#, query, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma *query* de consulta para um relatório, onde alguns campos de buscas são opcionais, exceto os intervalos de data.

Porém, ao realizar a consulta, a função sempre me retorna valores que não condiz com os parâmetros que passei no momento de execução da *query*

```
           public List<IQueryable> ObterNotaDetalhada(DateTime compInicial, DateTime compFinal, PorteContribuinte? codigoPorte, string query, int? itemServico, bool? simplesNacional)
           {
            var res = this.Servicos
            .Where(a => ((a.Competencia >= compInicial && a.Competencia <= compFinal) ||
                       (a.Prestador.Porte.Value == codigoPorte) || (a.Prestador.IsSimplesNacional == simplesNacional) ||
                         (a.ItemListaServico.Id == itemServico) ||
                         (a.Prestador.RazaoSocial.Contains(query) ||
                         a.Prestador.CpfCnpj.Contains(query))))
             .OrderByDescending(a => (a.id))
            .GroupBy(a => a.Prestador.CpfCnpj)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                CNPJ = g.Key,
                RazaoSocial = g.Select(x => x.Prestador.RazaoSocial),
                SimplesNacional = g.Select(x => x.Prestador.IsSimplesNacional),
                Porte = g.Select(x => x.Prestador.Porte),
                QtdNotasEmitidas = g.Count(),
                BaseDeCalculo = g.Select(x => x.BaseCalculo),
                ValorDeducoes = g.Select(x => x.ValorDeducoes),
                ValorServicos = g.Select(x => x.ValorServicos),
                ValorIss = g.Select(x => x.ValorInss),
                TotalBaseDeCalculo = g.Sum(x => x.BaseCalculo),
                TotalValorDeducoes = g.Sum(x => x.ValorDeducoes),
                TotalValorServicos = g.Sum(x => x.ValorServicos),
                TotalValorIss = g.Sum(x => x.ValorIss),
                IssRetido = g.Select(x => x.IssRetido > decimal.Zero),
                ItemDeServico = g.Select(x => x.ItemListaServico.Descricao),
                CodItemServico = g.Select(x=>x.ItemListaServico.Codigo)
            });
           return new List<IQueryable> { res };
            }
```

Os parâmetro que envio para o método:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Quando faço a busca apenas com os intervalos de datas, retorna tudo corretamente.

Um exemplo do resultado da busca:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na verdade o erro é na lógica que vc esta usando. Se o simples nacional for NÃO ou tiver porte, ele retorna. Isso quer dizer que, se o porte for 3, ele vai retornar mesmo que simples nacional seja SIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso ocorre devido a lógica aplicada no agrupamento das condições. No momento que você adiciona o `OR` (`||`), acaba que retornará o resultado que "casar" com uma ou outra.

Traduzindo para a seguinte "história" ficará mais fácil de compreender:

Filtrar os dados quando a competência for:

```
a.Competencia >= compInicial && a.Competencia <= compFinal
```

ou o Porte:

```
a.Prestador.Porte.Value == codigoPorte
```

ou é SimplesNacional:

```
a.Prestador.IsSimplesNacional == simplesNacional
```

ou o Id do Serviço:

```
a.ItemListaServico.Id == itemServico
```

ou a Razão Social Conter:

```
a.Prestador.RazaoSocial.Contains(query)
```

ou o CPF/CNPJ conter:

```
a.Prestador.CpfCnpj.Contains(query)
```

Dessa forma, uma condição verdadeira anula as demais condições, que podem ser falsas ou verdadeiras.

Se os filtros devem ser utilizados em conjunto, o operador `AND` (`&&`) deve ser utilizado. Se alguma cláusula é usada somente em alguns momentos, você pode usá-la separadamente utilizando `if`:

```
var res = this.Servicos.Where(a => (a.Competencia >= compInicial && a.Competencia <= compFinal));

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(codigoPorte)) res = res.Where(a => (a.Prestador.Porte.Value == codigoPorte);
if (simplesNacional) res = res.Where(a.Prestador.IsSimplesNacional == simplesNacional);

/** demais modificações na lista **/

return new List<IQueryable> { res };
```

Ps.: Não considerarei questões de performance.

Comment: Obg, Gabriel! Realmente, era erro meu na lógica dos operadores.

Answer (score 1):

**Outra opção:**

Como dito pelo Gabriel, teria que usar o operador `&&` invés do `||`

Você pode na `query lambda` verificar se o parâmetro é nulo e caso seja, retorna `true` que seria o equivalente a "dizer" no SQL que o campo é igual a ele mesmo. Para encurtar a resposta, vou colocar aqui só a parte do `Where`

```
public List<IQueryable> ObterNotaDetalhada(DateTime compInicial, DateTime compFinal, PorteContribuinte? codigoPorte, string query, int? itemServico, bool? simplesNacional)
{
    var res = this.Servicos
    .Where(a =>     (a.Competencia >= compInicial && a.Competencia <= compFinal) &&
                    (codigoPorte == null ? true : a.Prestador.Porte.Value == codigoPorte) && 
                    (simplesNacional == null ? true : a.Prestador.IsSimplesNacional == simplesNacional) &&
                    (itemServico == null ? true : a.ItemListaServico.Id == itemServico) &&
                    (query == null ? true : a.Prestador.RazaoSocial.Contains(query)) &&
                    (query == null ? true : a.Prestador.CpfCnpj.Contains(query)))
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Valeu, Barbetta! Ajudou demais!!!  =)